# How should I implement a list in of lists in Java? Or is there a better way than a list of lists?

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to make a variable offsets which equals ((2,1),(2,-1),(1,-2)) through which I can iterate and get the X,Y coordinates for each position.

In python, I would just use a list of lists. I thought I would be able to do this in Java, too, but it seems much more difficult to do so with this language...

I though maybe    int[] offsets   would work, but no dice, apparently. Then, as it's a list of lists (not just a list), I tried     int[][] offset     and eclipse still thought I was a moron.

What am I missing? Or am I just making this harder than it needs to be, and there's actually some really simple thing you'd suggest instead of a list of lists?

Comment: Why aren't you just using a `List` of `Point` objects? Java is an object-oriented languages. When you start constructing complicated nested collections of primitive values it's a good sign you're going about things the wrong way. Even in a language like C it'd be better practice to use an array of `structs`.

Comment: @TomG Python is also an OOPL, though; the gating issues are simplicity and where/how testing will be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best idea would be to use [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html)

```
Point point = new Point(1,4);
List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
```

---

Another way is to use list of lists. Not recommended. Not object oriented

```
 List<List<Integer>>
```

---

Alternatively you can create your version of Point class. For example an object which will have one axis inside

```
class AxisX{
 private List<Integer>
}
```

And put it inside another object

```
class Coordinates{
    private List<AxisX>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from what's written here, it looks like you're trying to access list members with array syntax.

In java, collections and arrays have completely different syntax.
arrays are indexed with [], collections such as lists use methods.

so to get the i'th element of the j'th list

```
list.get(j).get(i);
```

the first get call returns the list at the i'th index of list
the second get call, returns the j'th element of the inner list.

though for this case, I'll second @Tom_G and suggest using something like a point object
then you only need one list, the point handling x, y coordinates in a single object.

Answer (score 0):

if you will use this in something related to serialization and remote data transfer, try using the implementer classes of List, and not List itself (while declaring your variable), so not to get stuck in the middle, like

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ....
```

because the Collections framework interfaces dont extend the Serializable interface

maybe this helps, becuase i lived a horrible experience because i didnt notice this from the start